# Pausing a dataflow in Apache Flink and viewing the state of operators

Tags: java, akka, apache-flink

I am trying to address the following scenario:

I have a table of 1000 rows. I apply a map function to the rows of the table. After the dataflow has started, I want to randomly pause the execution of dataflow. Say,when I pause, 30 rows have been processed. So, the map operator should print its state i.e. *30 rows processed till now*. After some time, I can resume the execution.

Is it possible to do so in Flink?

Apache Flink uses Akka i.e. it implements `JobClient`, `JobManager` and `TaskManager` as `Akka` actors. In `Akka`, actors can define their own behaviors and communicate through messages. I implemented the pause functionality in Akka, where actors receive *Pause* message and pause their execution. So I think maybe I can pause the program by sending `JobManager` a pause message from `JobClient`. Can someone guide me on how to do this?

If not, are there other ways to achieve these functionalities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pausing Flink is not supported, as such. It would be difficult to coordinate a global pause across a cluster, and the benefit of such a feature is not obvious.

However, there are things you can do which might satisfy your objective(s). For example, if this is a streaming job, you could stop feeding in data. You could then inspect the values of various metrics, such as numRecordsIn, for the operators you are interested in.